# Java handson practise with diagrams

Tags: java

I need to pracise or code in java by seeing class diagrams, I mean inheritance diagrams, adding classes according to diagram and getting output.i googled for this type of diagramatic questions but i am unable to found.please help me. where can i find?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Class diagrams specify the inheritance relationships between and (if you go to the bother) the API details.  There's nothing in a class diagram that specifies any behavior that produces any output.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good UML book, and start solving the problems.

you can check this [Object Oriented Analysis and Design book by Grady booch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X)

Answer (score 0):

try [IBM Rational software architect](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/architect/).it has trail period of 30 days.
it has the both functionalities **reverse engineering** and **forward engineering** .
download source code of Java and try .

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm has a [community edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp) which allows for [reverse and forward engineering](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/provides/roundtripcodeengine.jsp). So you can see from both sides hands on.